# SignalR Connects fine first time, but when Reconnect is initiated, it doesn't complete Reconnect

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, signalr, signalr.client

I am using SignalR to push notifications to an angular application.

I have had it working before (although somewhat spotty it seemed), and now I am running into more issues regarding the reconnect.

I have gotten to the point where staring at the demo code of the documentation and others poeple code doesn't ever seem to work in SignalR like the claim it does. So I am posting my code to see if there is anything that I am blatently doing wrong that would not allow SignalR to work consistently and to start, reconnect, and disconnect consistantly.

I have a notification service that looks like the following:

```
.factory('Notification', ['$rootScope', '$log', '$localstorage', 'User', 'ENV', 'Events',
    function ($rootScope, $log, $localstorage, User, ENV, Events) {
        var self = this;

        this.proxy = null;
        this.connection = null;
        this.initializeSockets = function () {

            self.connection  = $.hubConnection(ENV.socketEndpoint, { useDefaultPath: true, logging: true })
            self.connection.qs = { token: User.getToken() };
            self.proxy = self.connection.createHubProxy('notificationEmitter');
            self.proxy.on('onNotification', function (notification) {
                $rootScope.$emit(notification.Topic, notification.Data);
            });

            if (self.connection.state === $.signalR.connectionState.disconnected) {
                self.connection.start(function () {})
                    .done(function (conn) {
                    $log.info('Connected to notification emitter');
                }).fail(function (a) {
                    $log.info('Unable to connect to connect:' + a)
                });
            }

            self.connection.starting = function (data) {
                $log.info('starting'); -> NEVER SEEMS TO GET CALLED
            }
            self.connection.disconnected = function (data) {
                $log.info('disconnected'); -> NEVER SEEMS TO GET CALLED
                setTimeout(function () {
                    proxy.connection.start();
                }, 20000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds
            };

            self.connection.reconnecting = function (data) {
                $log.info('reconnecting');
            }
            self.connection.reconnected = function (data) {
                $log.info('reconnected');
            }
            self.connection.connectionSlow = function (data) {
                $log.info('connectionSlow');
            }
            self.connection.error = function(error){
                $log.info('Signal R Error:' + error);
            }
        }

        $rootScope.$on(Events.userAuthenticated, function (event, user) {
            self.initializeSockets();
        })

        return self;

    }])
```

As I mentioned, it seems to connect most of the time the first time I start working on it, but after the first page refresh (and every time after) I get the following from the SignalR logs..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> starting: Raised before any data is sent over the connection.

So it's not related with connection.

> The OnReconnected event handler in a SignalR Hub can execute directly
>   after OnConnected but not after OnDisconnected for a given client. The
>   reason you can have a reconnection without a disconnection is that
>   there are several ways in which the word "connection" is used in
>   SignalR.

Reconnect occurs after connected. So it's normal you have never seen disconnected log.

> If the client stops running without having a chance to call the Stop
>   method, the server waits for the client to reconnect, and then ends
>   the SignalR connection after the disconnect timeout period.

So every refresh page you are doing this actually. You stop running connection without calling Stop.

If you don't have any problem, this lifetime cycle is pretty normal.

Check [more](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)